# sql server full text search strange search result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

i using SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2003 R2 for an article database. I have a field with the name of that article. Here are some examples:

- NYM-J 3X1,5 grau Ring 100 m
- NYM-O 3X1,5 grau Trommel
- NYM-O 3X1,5 grau    Ring 100 m
- NYM-J 3X1,5 grau Ring 50 m
- NYM-J 3X1,5 grau Trommel 500 m
- INSTALLATIONSLEITUNG NYM-J 3X1,5

When i use the following sql-command

```
SELECT Name FROM Articles WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"NYM-J 3X1,5"');
```

i expect that only articles with NYM-**J** 3X1,5 will be returned but all articles above so also with NYM-**O** are returned. So what i'am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sys.dm_fts_parser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to parse both strings:

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"NYM-J 3X1,5"', 1033, 0, 0)
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"NYM-O 3X1,5"', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Interpreting the results is a little awkward because the documentation doesn't cover all the details (for example, what does a `phrase_id` of zero mean?). But my best understanding is that the FTS parser has identified "nym" as a match, and "nymo" and "nymj" are both considered alternative forms of "nym" (because they have the same `group_id` but a different `phrase_id`). Therefore both search terms are identical, because FTS considers "nym", "nymj" and "nymo" to be equivalent for the purposes of full-text search.

Since there is very little documentation about the FTS parser, it's hard to say what a solution might be, although the most obvious one is that since you want a precise match you can just use `LIKE`. Full-text search is really intended for searching natural language text using words and phrases, it's not a general-purpose text parser.